# asp.net membership activity log

Tags: asp.net-membership

I am looking for a simple way to track user activity of an asp.net membership enabled site. I would like to see who is accessing what pages and when, total visits for each page, etc.

Are there any open free solutions out there or a good example?

Comment: It's unfortunate that the asp.net-membership does not log the username to the IIS log.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this article: [Tracking User Activity](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Tracking-User-Activity.aspx).

From the article:

> Many ASP.NET web applications support user accounts, enabling visitors to create an account and sign in to the site. With a little bit of effort you can track the activity of your logged on users. This can include recording activities such as what pages were visited as well as what actions were performed. Consider a page that allows a user to manage his profile. When first arriving at this page the activity log might add an entry like "Visiting the User Profile page." After updating his e-mail address, the activity log might record, "Changed e-mail address from scott@example.com to mitchell@example.com." Such usage tracking offers a deeper level of analysis than is possible with log files or online visitor statistic tools. Instead of data that report total number of visitors or how the average user is interacting with the site, user activity tracking can provide a very detailed view of how a particular individual is using the application and what actions he is performing while signed on to the site.
>
> This article examines how to record your users' activities in a database table and display this information in a web page. A complete, working demo application that shows these techniques in action is available for download.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but it might be a start:

[Track your visitors using an HttpModule](http://madskristensen.net/post/Track-your-visitors-using-an-HttpModule.aspx)